# AWS Glue Reading JSON in Parallel

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

Good afternoon !

I need to make a JOB GLUE that needs to read 17 million JSONs (1 JSON per client) and write to parquet.

But when I use spark.read.json(read_path_s3) it doesn't process in parallel, having a horrible performance.

Is there any way to do the reading in parallel?

Comment: Is this one big file comprised of all 17m records?

Comment: No, it's 17 million JSONs, each JSON is 1 record

Comment: Assuming `read_path_s3` is the location of all 17m json files, spark should be reading these in parallel.  The poor performance is likely due to the overhead of scheduling and processing of 17m small files.  You could experiment with the number of workers?   Maybe file compaction using something other than spark?

Comment: Yes, the problem is probably because of the "small files"
I made some attempts to read 1000 JSONs and write 1 parquet file, but it's not a performative process either...
While looking for solutions, I saw a solution using sc.parallelize(list_address_jsons).map(function_convert_address_to_info_json) but I couldn't get it to work...
sc.parallelize works in parallel, the problem that it needs a list of contents in JSON format. To create this list, I read each JSON individually, get the content and save it in a list variable. When I read 1000 JSONs I run sc.parallelize.